# Changing the data based on the value selected through dropdown box in angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a dropdown from which i can select two values and the corresponding values are displayed but instead of the data  i want to display a data which is inside a **div tag**.

Here is [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gkJve/158/)

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <select id="sel" class="input-block-level" ng-model="list_category" ng-options="obj.id as obj.name for obj in list_categories.data"></select>
    <p>$scope.list_category: {{list_category}}</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.list_categories = {
        data: [{
            id: 'id1',
            name: 'name1'
        }, {
            id: 'id2',
            name: 'name2'
        }]
    };
    $scope.list_category = 'id1';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-include`. To include a data from an url or template file.

```
<select id="sel" class="input-block-level" ng-model="list_category" ng-options="obj.url as obj.name for obj in list_categories.data"></select>

<div ng-include='list_category'></div>

function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.list_categories = {
        data: [{
            id: 'id1',
            name: 'name1',
            url : 'template1.html'
        }, {
            id: 'id2',
            name: 'name2',
            url : 'template2.html'
        }]
    };
    $scope.list_category = 'template1.html';
}
```

Comment: One more thing is there a way where i can select a particular div inside a page?

Comment: No, wherever the ng-include directive is add, template will be rendered in those elements.

Comment: I didnt get what u told